# A Conic Locus Problem

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Problem:

> From any fixed point in the axis of a general conic, a line is drawn perpendicular to the tangent at $P$ (on the conic) meeting $SP$ in $R$ where $S$ is the focus. Show that the locus of $R$ is a circle.

I don't really know where to start from, I drew the diagram and now I am stuck. My attempt was to consider four points on conic and show that the four corresponding points $R$ are cyclic but I fail to do so.

Comment: By a “general conic,” I take it that you mean a nondegenerate conic, yes?

Comment: @amd Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show the proof for an ellipse, the other cases are analogous.

In an ellipse, the bisector $PH$ of $\angle SPS'$ (where $S'$ is the second focus) is perpendicular to the tangent at $P$. It follows that triangles $SPH$ and $SDR$ are similar ($D$ is the fixed point on axis $SS'$) and $SR:SP=SD:SH$, that is:
$$
SR={SP\over SH}SD.
$$
On the other hand, from the angle bisector theorem we have
$SP:S'P=SH:S'H$, that is:
$$
{SP\over SH}={SP+S'P\over SH+S'H}={a\over c},
$$
where $2a$ is the ellipse major axis and $2c=SS'$.
Inserting this result into the previous equation we obtain that $SR$ is constant, hence $R$ belongs to a circle of centre $S$ and radius ${a\over c}SD$.

[image]

Comment: A small confusion (1) and a doubt (2)... 1) *Why is the bisector of angle SPS' acting as normal?* (I haven't studied Ellipse particularly yet, in my class we are first dealing with General Conic geometrically, and then parabola geometrically, then standard parabola on Cartesian plane and it's results, then ellipse and then hyperbola.) 2) About which axis can I consider S' mirror image of S in a non degenerate conic?

Comment: @ChiefVS (1) See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Focus-to-focus_reflection_property; (2) $S'$ is the reflection of $S$ about the centre of the conic, or about the minor/conjugate axis (for ellipse/hyperbola respectively).

Comment: Ok thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Aretino.. $ \frac{SH}{SP}=\frac{SD}{SR}= $ 1/eccentricity ... so nice a result !

Comment: You had a nice figure. I don't see it any longer...

Comment: @JeanMarie The figure I made for this answer is in place and visible, for me at least.

Comment: My bad ! My screen was "blocked" at the end of your text...

Answer (score 1):

(I will refer to the excellent drawing and notations in the solution by Aretino, my solution being in the same spirit).

It is a consequence of the following property of an ellipse  (see proof below) :

The locus of the (variable) symmetrical point $T$ of one of the foci, say $S'$,  with respect to a varying tangent is a circle $C$ centered in the other focus $F$ with radius $2a$ (this is rather well known by the "paper folding construction of an ellipse" : see http://kuzeemath.blogspot.com/2013/11/3-different-methods-to-conic-sections.html). The final circle (red circle in Aretino's drawing) is obtained by taking the homothetic image of circle $C$ using the homothety with center $F$ that sends $S'$ onto $D$ : we find back in this way the radius $2a\dfrac{SD}{2c}$ obtained by Aretino.

**Proof :** the above property is an immediate consequence of the bi-focal definition of an ellipse :

$$SM+MS'=2a \ \iff SM+MT=2a \ \iff \ ST=2a$$

if we take for $M$ the tangency point.

Comment: Interesting approach, hadn't seen (yet) use of Homothety and Dilation used outside of Contest maths involving Triangles, Quads and Circles.  Thanks, took me a while to understand and draw it out :p